# DNN 9 User Registration - How to Include Custom API Post to Click Event?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

We have a DNN 9.2 site from which we need to collect additional information at time of user registration.  We are utilizing the user profile fields, creating new ones for our purposes, and have written an asynchronous method that sends this information to a payment gateway API.

When a user clicks the Register button, how do we add our CreatePayer method as a click event or similar modality such that the user profile information is sent to the API for review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use one of the available forms modules to build a custom registration page:  Action Forms, Open Forms, and Xmod Pro.

Each of those modules comes with the tools not only to build the forms but also to include custom additions to the submit button click event.

As an example, you can build a registration form with Action Form to include complete user registration, collection of custom profile data, and custom processing on submission.

The only development that you would need to do is build a custom On Click Handler send data to the payment processor.  If this is something as simple as passing data to the payment processor through a POST or other Web API, then that is close to being there, and almost none (or no) code would be required.

I mention Action Form only because it is more familiar to me.  The other two can do the job, too.